# React Native WebComponent Expo Android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I develop a library as webcomponent it is works on html pure and React JS and react native web browser, but when i made expo as android show many log errors, what is the correct way to inicializate a script js on React Native[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import "./assets/scripts/wal-me";
import "./assets/scripts/wal-me-header";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends Component {

render = () => {
return (
  <div className="App" id="root">
    <wal-me id="comunica"></wal-me>
    <wal-me-header></wal-me-header>
  </div>
);
```

};
}

Comment: Traduce tu pregunta.